# User control click binding not working

Tags: c#, user-controls

I have a problem with my user control(SefAttributes.ascx). I have 2 textbox, 1 label and 1 button in my user control.In main page(SantiyeGiris2.aspx), I am data binding.I am adding this user control dynamically and I want to delete that row when user clicks delete button, but my click event not working.

My user control code behind like below:

```
public event EventHandler SefSilClicked;

protected void btnSefSil_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.SefSilClicked != null)
    {
        this.SefSilClicked(this, e);
    }
}
```

In SantiyeGiris2.aspx.cs I am binding like:

```
protected void rptSantifeSefDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    SefAttributes sa = (SefAttributes)(e.Item.FindControl("sfDiv"));
    SantiyePersonel sp = (SantiyePersonel)(e.Item.DataItem);
    sa.txtSefBas.Text = sp.BaslangicFormatlanmis;

    if (Convert.ToDateTime(sa.txtSefBas.Text) < System.DateTime.Now)
        sa.txtSefBas.Enabled = false;

    sa.txtSefBit.Text = sp.BitisFormatlanmis;
    sa.lbl.Text = sp.PersonelTamAdi;

    sa.SefSilClicked += new EventHandler(RptSefSilClicked);
}
```

and click function

```
protected void RptSefSilClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    YP_SANTIYE.WindowScripts.Alert("click activated.");
}
```

I can't see the problem.I will grateful if anyone can help me.

Comment: You mean does not fired? Also, I guess it's asp.net right? can we have a look at markup page?

Comment: Yeah,it does not fired.Everytime SefSilClicked attributes is null and it is asp.net

Comment: Did you bind the items again on page load?

Comment: Actually, I am adding user control dynamically with add button,for some reason I have to give repeater datasource and databind in just page load not postback.

Comment: You have to bind the items again on post back@@"

Comment: If I bind items on postback I will lost my content of my repeater

Comment: I get the problem thamks.